# why volatile is faster without optimizations enabled

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, cpu-cache

Here's a simple code I wrote when I was bored during a meeting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>


int main() {
    long long a = 0;
    
    long long until = 1000000000;
    for (long long i = 0; i < until; i++) {
        a += i;
    }

    printf("%lld\n", a);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I add a `volatile` qualifier to my variable `a`, my code runs nearly x3 faster.

**Platform: g++ 9.4.0 ubuntu 20.04 intel i7 x86_64**

### Benchmarks

```
No optimization:
===============
volatile
499999999500000000

real    0m0.409s
user    0m0.405s
sys 0m0.004s
====================
normal
499999999500000000

real    0m1.672s
user    0m1.672s
sys 0m0.000s
```

If I enable optimizations things quickly change

```
Level 1 optimization (-O1)
==========================

volatile
499999999500000000

real    0m0.237s
user    0m0.235s
sys 0m0.000s
====================
normal
499999999500000000

real    0m0.228s
user    0m0.223s
sys 0m0.004s

Level 2 optimization (-O2)
==========================

volatile
499999999500000000

real    0m0.237s
user    0m0.235s
sys 0m0.000s
====================
normal
499999999500000000

real    0m0.228s
user    0m0.223s
sys 0m0.004s

Level 3 optimization (-O3)
==========================

volatile
499999999500000000

real    0m0.248s
user    0m0.248s
sys 0m0.000s
====================
normal
499999999500000000

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s
```

I couldn't understand why volatile access is faster if we don't enable optimizations. Also, I wonder why it does not benefit from cache hits when the variable is not volatile.

Comment: _"without optimizations enabled"_ every performance question after this is pointless.

Comment: Are you sure you are measuring a right thing? This kind of simple loops compilers are able to optimize away and replace with equation for sum.  Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/nocPbq4j7

Comment: assembly is fairly similar: https://godbolt.org/z/46G3ecK8f but as said above measuring the performance of unoptimised code is fairly pointless

Comment: You should declare `until` as `const` since the variable doesn't change its value after initialization.  Look at the assembly language before and after this change.

Comment: @PasserBy this is not the point of the question, this is curiosity and I wanna learn more about the behavior and what's going on under the hood

Comment: My guess is that the loop is miss-aligned when volatile is not used. This can also be the case for data (since their location appear to change too). This is a *side effect* happening because the compiler do not care about the alignement in unoptimized code. Details like this mater a lot for performance and this is the goal of compiler to consider them while performing optimisations. If you explicitly not enable optimizations, then you should not be surprised having such weird effects... I cannot agree more with the comment of Passer By.

Comment: `volatile` tells the compiler to not optimize usage of the the variable as well as as it potentially could. When the rest of the code around it is optimized, usage of the `volatile`  variable is going to stand out as slow. Here's one of the best "Under the hood" tools out there: https://godbolt.org/z/PKnT73njs Note how the optimized, non-`volatile` version has eliminated the loop completely by precomputing the answer of 499999999500000000

Comment: Here's a [side-to-side comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/8d7vqbjGY). The code *with* volatile does emit two addition `mov` instructions in the critical loop on -O0 but I can confirm that it does run about 14% faster on my machine. I think this is a worthwhile question, even without compiler optimisation.